# Multiple Raspberry Pi zeros (no wifi) + touchscreen. Daisy-chained communication?

Tags: gpio, spi

I'm trying to devise a solution that will connect multiple Raspberry Pi zeros together for communication between them. I'm using a touchscreen on each of them, so GPIO pins 1-24 are taken. Also, I'm using the RPi zero model without wifi. Would I be able to use pins 25-40 to communicate? Can I use SPI on these pins? I would prefer a daisy-chained solution but hub and spoke is ok if necessary.

Comment: What physical communication media are you planning to use ? For example "point to point wire "? Are you describing using GPIO pins  or  hardware header pins ?

Comment: Why don't you just use the UART?  You should be able to create a second one to daisy chain (the one that's used on the bluetooth versions and lacks a proper clock), or else you could stick with hub and spoke and come up with a protocol to prevent conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

You still have USB on RPi Zero, meaning you could attach any USB communication dongle you want (including WiFi or Ethernet) and use the appropriate networking architecture. Daisy-chaining is not out of the question with Ethernet, but that would require 2 network adapters per RPi, so a hub+nodes architecture will be more efficient.

Comment: if you want to go fancy and really wish to make a linear topology you can also choose some usb to serial adapter and go for CAN or MODBUS (or other buses) without using hubs and switches